# Ubuntu 16.04 - Applications becoming very unstable

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, google-chrome, syslog

I recently updated to Ubuntu 15.10 where these issues seemed to be occurring and currently having a similar situation on 16.04. I've also recently just changed graphics cards from an old ATI card to a Nvidia 210 so this could be the culprit but seems strange.

It seems the longer my session using the computer, the more unstable it becomes.

Google Chrome is usually the application I notice becoming unstable, getting the "Aw Snap" screen a lot. I've tried disabling hard acceleration and recreating my profile file for Chrome and those haven't seemed to have worked.

Here are some Chrome errors from the syslog if these help at all:

```
May 18 09:27:47 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [76338.282424] chrome[1104]: segfault at 100 ip 00007fa695a7f393 sp 00007ffeb84bff70 error 4 in libpepflashplayer.so[7fa694f14000+10c5000]
May 18 09:27:56 UBUNTU-STUART gnome-session[1720]: [WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
May 18 09:28:26 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [76377.906585] chrome[1329]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fa695a8921c sp 00007ffeb84bc670 error 4 in libpepflashplayer.so[7fa694f14000+10c5000]
May 18 09:29:33 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [76444.766900] chrome[1413]: segfault at 8000 ip 000055d46fb0500a sp 00007ffeb84bf9c0 error 4 in chrome[55d46d480000+5b21000]
May 18 09:29:36 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [76448.112405] chrome[1424]: segfault at 10 ip 000055d46fb09823 sp 00007ffeb84bfa80 error 4 in chrome[55d46d480000+5b21000]
May 18 09:29:51 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [76462.775217] chrome[1436]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffeb84bf508 error 14
May 18 09:28:31 UBUNTU-STUART gnome-session[1720]: [WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
May 18 10:12:16 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [79007.192584] chrome[3267]: segfault at 55d472fe2258 ip 000055d46fd1cf27 sp 00007ffeb84bf760 error 7 in chrome[55d46d480000+5b21000]
May 18 10:14:13 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [79124.742371] chrome[3181]: segfault at 1cdfe9300008 ip 000055d46fd5bc54 sp 00007ffeb84c01c0 error 4 in chrome[55d46d480000+5b21000]
May 18 10:14:17 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [79128.325128] traps: chrome[3211] general protection ip:55d46faecba0 sp:7ffeb84c0288 error:0 in chrome[55d46d480000+5b21000]
May 18 10:14:27 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [79138.621681] chrome[3234]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffeb84be438 error 14
May 18 10:14:27 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [79138.848178] chrome[2408]: segfault at 120 ip 000055f2dad466b3 sp 00007fff3ee6e310 error 4 in chrome[55f2da0da000+5b21000]
```

I recently noticed Sublime Text 3 just closing without any errors being displayed, but found this in the syslog:

```
May 18 10:13:12 UBUNTU-STUART kernel: [79063.575066] sublime_text[3141]: segfault at 7ff000000000 ip 00000000004f54e8 sp 00007ffda61bd530 error 6 in sublime_text[400000+521000]
```

Now I then I also get errors popping up saying various stuff has stopped working like git, apt and samba. But then seems to start working almost immediately after.

I know this is pretty vague and there's not a whole lot that can be done but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have had several problems with both Nvidea and the 16.04 upgrade tool. Try installing a different desktop environment. That way, you will know if it's Unity messing up on you or Ubuntu itself. I recommend Gnome.

1. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type ****sudo apt-get install gnome****
2. Now you must investigate. There could be a few things that happen now: all files failed to "fetch", in the download process, the system asks about adding an entry to **unity-greeter**, or the operation completes successfully.
   A. Try typing **ping google.com**. If that doesn't work, check your internet connection and try again. If it still doesn't work, check Ubuntu Software Center. If that doesn't pull up, try again later or, if your dual-booting, try the Internet in the different OS.
   B. If it asks about adding an entry, **click yes. This is very important.** You can now continue on.
   C. Continue on if it is successful.
3. Type **sudo reboot**.
4. Now you should see a bar above your name in the login screen that may say **Default** or **Unity** or something else. Click it, and select **Gnome**.
5. Try using some of the applications that crashed before, except now, use them in gnome. If they work fine and don't crash, open a terminal **in gnome** and type **sudo unity --reset**. If that doesn't work, a more risky approach would be **sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity**. If they crash the same, try reinstalling Ubuntu from a bootable USB or CD.
6. If that didn't work then there could be an error in your installation ISO. Download a new one, and then try. If it still doesn't work, open up your PC (**physically**) and check to make sure any components aren't broken. You should also check on the PC if the memory is messed up with **memtest**, or try seeing if any information is available with **lm_sensors**.

If you need any other help or if I didn't make myself clear please let me know, as I am very willing to help.

Comment: Followed your steps and still was doing similar things, so decided to do a MemTest on the system, turns out one of the sticks of RAM was shattered. Had 65536+ errors, surprised the computer was running at all. Your steps helped me narrow down what was causing this though so not sure if I should mark as answer or submit an answer saying it was faulty memory?

Comment: I edited the answer a bit. Didn't even think about the ram! But now that you know, if you want, I post a question and answer that shows how to make Ubuntu run even with under 500mb of ram! Anyway, you could post a new question saying that you checked my instructions and then found out it was the ram physically broken, or mark mine correct now that I edited it, or just post a completely different answer. I work hard on each and every one of my answers, so I would appreciate you using mine, but it really doesn't matter. It's whatever you want to do.